# Какое свойство показывает кординаты нахождения мыши?

Tags: javascript

Какое свойство показывает кординаты нахождения мыши?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете определить свои собственные переменные и хранить в них координаты мыши

```
var X = 0;
var Y = 0;

$().mousemove(function (e) {
    X = e.pageX;
    Y = e.pageY;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы ответ Tool Tip заработал, нужно не забыть загрузить jQuery:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```